# Why does my c++ program appear to hang

Tags: c++, function, encryption, converters, freeze

I'm writing a program that is supposed to take a string, remove all spaces and punctuation from the string, then convert all characters to uppercase and increment them by 13 spaces. The professor who expects this from me demands that I use functions for the processing of the program. I wrote it following this parameters but for some reason after typing in a sentence, such as 'This is a line!', the program seems to just hang up. If I run the debugger step by step then the program seems to run fine. I'm not sure where I am going wrong and the professor forbids us from us seeking help from classmates. Since he said nothing about seeking help online I thought I'd turn here after finding this site.

My program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void convert(string text, int& i,int length);
void RemovePunc(string text, int& i,int length);
void RemoveSpac(string text, int& i,int length);
void MakeUpper(string text, int i,int length);

int main() 
{
    string text;
    int i;
    int length;


    cout << "Enter your text: ";
    getline(cin, text);

    length = (int)text.length();

    convert(text, i, length);

    return 0;
}

void convert(string text, int& i,int length)
{
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++) 
    {
        RemovePunc(text, i, length);
        RemoveSpac(text, i, length);
        MakeUpper(text, i, length);

    }
    cout << "Encrypted text:\n" << text << endl;
}

void RemovePunc(string text, int& i,int length)
{
    if (ispunct(text[i]))
        {
            text.erase(i--, 1);
            length = text.size();
        }
}

void RemoveSpac(string text, int& i,int length)
{
    if (isspace(text[i]))
        {
            text.erase(i--, 1);
            length = text.size();
        }
}

void MakeUpper(string text, int i,int length)
{
    if (isalpha(text[i])) 
        {
            text[i] = toupper(text[i]);

            for (int counter = 0; counter < 13; counter++) 
            {
                if (text[i] == 'Z')
                    text[i] = 'A';
                else
                    text[i]++;

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Beware that `length` changes are not propagated between your functions. Have a look at the difference of call-by-reference and call-by-value.

Comment: Why passing `string` by value?

Comment: @GenCrash10 What does statement "...increment them by 13 spaces" mean?

Comment: This is much easier if your functions are actually functions - i.e. they return a new string - and you finish one step before you proceed with the next. Use a loop inside each transformation function, don't pass `i` and `length` around.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I believe it means "implement ROT-13".

Answer (score 0):

I think, it is a bad idea to send counter `i` to text transformation functions without initialization.

So, the first suggestion: initialize `i` in `main` function, or rewrite code in order not to send `i` in `convert`, `RemovePunc`, etc.

The second suggestion is about sending string to text transformation functions: functions like `void convert(string text, int& i,int length);` make a copy of text to work with data inside and do not change data outside. Your functions must change `text`, so it is better to use pointer to string, or reference, like:

```
 void convert(string &text, int& i,int length);
 void RemovePunc(string &text, int& i,int length);
 void RemoveSpac(string &text, int& i,int length);
 void MakeUpper(string &text, int i,int length);
```